# PDO fetch not returning any row from the table

Tags: php, pdo

Why is my PDO fetch not returning any rows from the table?

```
    $sql = "SELECT * from ts_rounds WHERE current=:current";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
    $stm->execute( array( ':current' => 1 ) );
    $rows = $stm->fetch();
    echo $row["name"];
```

Comment: `$rows = $stm->fetch(); echo $row["name"];`. `$row` and `$rows` is not the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the : after the = in your 1st line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from ts_rounds WHERE current=:current";
```